# How to navigate a website ,hover mouse over sub menu and click on a website using selenium python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium

I was trying to automate one of my web application "maximo" by using selenium python.
I am able to login with username and password and also to click on any single button using "find_element_by_"etc.But I don't know how to hover mouse over sub menu and click.

Also I was trying to find a means to call Javascript code corresponding to a menu,which are shown ata the bottom of this maximo(picture attached).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbWxK.jpg)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browserchr3=webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
browserchr3.get('http://da-maximo.dca.com/maximo/webclient/login/login.jsp?welcome=true')
browserchr3.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('bhsek015'+Keys.TAB)

userpassword=browserchr3.find_element_by_id('password')
userpassword
userpassword.send_keys('Adil@2020')
userpassword.submit()
#browserchr3.execute_script(topLevelMenus['m7f8f3e49_ns_mc'].menuClick({"id":"WOTRACK_APP","text":"Work Order Tracking","eventvalue":"WOTRACK","apptype":"RUN","target":"startcntr","event":"changeapp","value":"WOTRACK"}))
browserchr3.implicitly_wait(10)                      

Select(browserchr3.find_element_by_css_selector('#m7f8f3e49_ns_menu_WO_MODULE_a')).select_by_visible_text("Work Order Tracking")
wo
wo.click()
browserchr3.implicitly_wait(10)
wot=browserchr3.find_element_by_css_selector('#menuholdertd')
wot
wot.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question 1, hovering over element, you need to use Action Chains

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(browserchr3)
# Assuming wot is the element to move your mouse to
actions.move_to_element(wot)
actions.perform()    #Performs chained action
```

You can chain actions like this 
    ActionChains(browserchr3).move_to_element(wot).perform()

For full reference, have a look at API => https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

For Question 2, how to execute javascript,

```
browserchr3.execute_script('Script statement')
```

Comment: Thanks,though your code does not give any error but,it opens main menu,but does not go to sub menu and click,but just flickers the main menu and does nothing.

Comment: You need to further chain it. If 'menu' is the element you hover your mouse, and 'sub_menu' is element you actually click, try doing something like this.
ActionChains(browserchr3).move_to_element(menu).pause(1).move_to_element(sub_menu).click().perform()

This can be split in multiple statements too...